# PHP Tweet script for PHP 4.4.9

Tags: php, twitter

As I am stuck on PHP 4.4.9 with my server, I was looking for a PHP Script. Unforunately, all scripts that I've found are only supported by PHP 5+. I am now asking here whether someone of you could help me out?

I only need to post some Tweets via a PHP Script, nothing more. Maybe its still possible via CURL?

Answer (score 1):

If you know which features it is that the scripts use that are exclusive to PHP 5, you can write your own functions to replace them.  In most cases "PHP 5" scripts use a handful of new functions ([full list here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.functions.php)).

For example, if you don't have access to the function `file_put_contents()` on your server, you could use the following block to simulate it (and remove any errors issued by calling a non-existent function):

```
if (!function_exists('file_put_contents'))
{
    function file_put_contents($fname, $data)
    {
        $out = fopen($fname, 'w');
        if (!$out) { return FALSE; }
        
        fwrite($out, $data);
        fclose($out);
        return strlen($data);
    }
}
```

(**Note:** I'm aware that `file_put_contents()` has more parameters than the example, but code to handle it can be added as needed.)

It's not the best solution, but if only a few things need tweaking and you have no other option, it may be worth considering.

Comment: Thanks, I will remember this for the future! Sadly this isnt the case here. But thanks anyways :)

Answer (score -1):

This is what I have implemented using CURL

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "status=I like pie");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "userid:password");
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);`
```

Comment: $url <--- How is this defined?

Comment: Twitter no longer supports username/password authenticaiton for their API. You need to use [OAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth_overview).